# Adjusting big or small screens using geometry reader

Tags: swift, swiftui

I am currently stuck in trouble i am not really able to resize image and texts to fit bigger or small screens. This is just a simple card that i want to be able to be resizable and should be in the same proportions. I have even tried geometry reader. I am having trouble as even if I have used geometry reader reader the white spaces I wanted are not there as the picture takes the entire width and height which looks bad not ideal. If there is a way for me to have the same proportion of the card for all different screen sizes then I am all open to ideas.

Image of my card:

[image]

Here is my code:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Image("shops")
                .resizable()
                .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
                
            
            VStack {
                
                Spacer()
                Text("Welcome to MarketInfo")
                
                    .font(.largeTitle)
                    .fontWeight(.semibold)
                    .foregroundColor(.white)

                
            }
            .padding(.bottom, 30)
            .frame(width: 400)
        }
        .frame(width: 380, height: 270)
        .cornerRadius(20)
        .clipped()
        .shadow(radius: 8)
        .padding(.top, 20)
        
}
}
struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        Group {
            ContentView()
            ContentView()
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think where you are running into issues is in using the fixed frame. The issue with using it is that it does not adjust for sizes. If you had something complicated, you could use a `GeometryReader` to resize the frame based on a proportion of the available space. However, the simplest implementation is setting your `Text` as an `.overlay()` on your image and setting the `.aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)`.

The code would now be:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Image("shops")
            .resizable()
            .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
            .overlay(
                VStack {
                    Spacer()
                    Text("Welcome to MarketInfo")
                    
                        .font(.largeTitle)
                        .fontWeight(.semibold)
                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                }
            )
            .cornerRadius(20)
            .clipped()
            .shadow(radius: 8)
            .padding(30)
    }
}
```

The overlay is never bigger than the `Image`, which can be an issue using a `ZStack`, and it will move with the `Image`. I then just through some padding on the `Image` all around to keep it in from the sides, and away from other views.

Comment: Hi, Sorry for the late reply. How do I make the image bigger if there is no way for me to fix the size. Also using Spacer() to move the image upwards does not really work. Is there a way to push items up using points.

Comment: You can stick the image in a `.frame` and have be any size you want. And yes, you can specify the exact amount of `.padding` you want as well. Remember, however, that this will fix the size for ALL screen sizes. You can also use a `GeometryReader` and make everything percentages of the screen size if you want. I was just throwing an example together for you. Putting things exactly where you want them takes some time playing with the view.

Answer (score 0):

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ZStack() {
            Image("shops")
                .resizable()
                .aspectRatio(1.4, contentMode: .fit) // 380 / 270 = 1.4
                .overlay(
                    VStack {
                        Spacer()
                        Text("Welcome to MarketInfo")
                            .font(.largeTitle)
                            .fontWeight(.semibold)
                            .foregroundColor(.white)
                            .lineLimit(1)
                            .minimumScaleFactor(0.5)
                            .padding()
                    })
        }
        // .frame is not required, but Change .infinity to a number will resize the card
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
        .cornerRadius(20)
        .shadow(radius: 8)
        .padding(.horizontal, 20)
    }
}
struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        
        ContentView()
            .previewDevice("iPhone 13 Pro")
        ContentView()
            .previewDevice("iPod touch (7th generation)")
        ContentView()
            .previewDevice("iPad Pro (12.9-inch) (5th generation)")
    }
}
```